# passing event handler as reference

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

this is an exercise from codecademy. Why does it require to pass the event handler as a reference? why i can't type `onClick={goBack()}` instead of `onClick={goBack}`

```
const goBack = () => {
    setQuestionIndex(prevQuestionIndex => prevQuestionIndex - 1);
  }

....

 <button onClick={goBack}>
          Go Back
 </button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are using `onClick={goBack()}` then you are invoking/calling the function `goBack` and the result of `goBack` invocation get passed to `onClick`

**Live Demo**

[image: Codesandbox Demo]

But If you are using as `onClick={goBack}`, then In this case you are passing a `reference` to the `onClick` which means when user `click` on the button then It will automatically invoke the function. You don't have to invoke the function yourself.

---

**1) Let say consider function with value**

```
<button onClick={fun()}> button with function reference</button>
```

If you are passing value to a function then first of all it will produces a `warning` in the console as:

```
Warning:
Expected `onClick` listener to be a function, instead got a value of `string` type.
```

and when you invoke it then it will throw `error` as

```
Error
Expected `onClick` listener to be a function, instead got a value of `string` type.
```

**2) If you are using as**

```
<button onClick={fun}> button with function reference</button>
```

then function `fun` will be passed as a `prop` and when use click on the function then this function `fun` will get invoked automatically

Comment: @Hussam No both are not same thing

Answer (score 0):

`goBack` is a reference to a function, `goBack()` calls that function and returns the result.

In the case of the click handler for a button, of course, you want the function to run when the button is clicked, not when the button is rendered. That's why you need to pass the function, rather than calling it (on render) and passing its result.

Answer (score 0):

If you pass in the function call instead of the reference, it will call the function as soon as your component renders, the reference is bound to the click handler, hence when the specific event triggers, it will callout to the reference.

Here is a snippet to see this,
[Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/admiring-wave-pxox3?file=/src/App.js)